# Unable to GET or POST Teams Tabs in Power Automate using the Office 365 HTTP connector

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams, office365api, power-automate, microsoft-planner

Trying to GET or POST Teams tabs.
I get the same error when trying to delete Planner plans.

ALL of these operations works with the EXACT same URI in Graph Explorer.
As you can see below getting Teams Tab works in one tenant (where I have no particular admin roles)
In the tenant where it is not working I am Global Admin and owner of the teams & planners in  questions.

I have contacted MS support but don't have high expectations they will find a solution.

So:

1. Working with Graph Explorer
2. Working in one tenant but not another
3. Working with the premium HTTP connector.

What could this be about. I have matched the licenses between the two different tenants.
Any permissions deep in Azure missing? I am out of ideas, and this is quite important as I am building a project where they expect be to automate Tab creation and Planner removal.

My query:
[image: My Query:]

Error (To the left is one tenant, to the rioght another where it is working.:
[image: Error]

Full error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-10-14T19:54:08",
      "request-id": "xxx",
      "client-request-id": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Power Automate, tried to get list of tabs in Teams Channel using HTTP connector (Instead of using O365 HTTP connector as its giving "NotFound" error) and got success code 200.Got success code using Graph Explorer and Postman as well

- Used the tenant where I am Global Admin and owner of the teams.

Steps followed:
[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, yes I know this. It is working for me both using the HTTP connector and Graph Exlorer, but not the Office 365 Groups HTTP connector for some reason.
The customer in this case will not have access to premium connectors so unfortunately this is not an option.